# how to use metatrader 4 predefine variable

Tags: metatrader4

How do i use the predefined variable like Open[],Close[],High[],low[]? I cant get my code working, it is as if the variable has no data in it when i run it in EA tester. Sorry guys, im not from programming background, but i do understand basic programming.

void OnTick()
{

```
  if (OrdersTotal()==0)//if we have no open orders
  
  double ma20    = iMA(NULL,0,20,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
  double ma200   = iMA(NULL,0,200,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
  double rsi     = iRSI(NULL,0,12,PRICE_OPEN,0);

        if (ma20>ma200 && rsi<65 && Close[1]<Open[1] && High[1]>Open[1] && High[0]>High[1])     
   
           //send a buy order
           int buyticket = OrderSend
           (
           Symbol(),                        //Currency pair on the chart
           OP_BUY,                          //Buy/sell Command
           0.01,                            //Lot Size
           Ask,                             //Price for the command
           3,                               //Slippage usually 3
           Ask-100*_Point,                  //Stoploss
           Ask+100*_Point,                  //Take Profit                            
           NULL,                            //Commend
           0,                               //Magic No
           0,                               //Expiry
           Green                            //Arrow colour
        
           );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, however you haven't properly used brackets to allow your if statements to operate correctly.

```
if (OrdersTotal()==0)//if we have no open orders
{
   double ma20    = iMA(NULL,0,20,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
   double ma200   = iMA(NULL,0,200,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
   double rsi     = iRSI(NULL,0,12,PRICE_OPEN,0);

   if (ma20>ma200 && rsi<65 && Close[1]<Open[1] && High[1]>Open[1] && High[0]>High[1])     
   {
      //send a buy order
      int buyticket = OrderSend
      (
         Symbol(),                        //Currency pair on the chart
         OP_BUY,                          //Buy/sell Command
         0.01,                            //Lot Size
         Ask,                             //Price for the command
         3,                               //Slippage usually 3
         Ask-100*_Point,                  //Stoploss
         Ask+100*_Point,                  //Take Profit                            
         NULL,                            //Commend
         0,                               //Magic No
         0,                               //Expiry
         Green                            //Arrow colour
     );
   }
}
```